# How to display a search and select form in place of a text box in c# or VB.net. The search form should look like a dropdown box to the user

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, winforms

I have a billing form as displayed below.I want to show products. I can use a combo box instead of product textbox. but since I have 100000 record of products, combo box is not a good option. Instead, As the cursor enter the product text box, I want to display another form with textbox and datagrid view exactly in the place of product text box.(it looks like a combobox for the user). The user can then search and select a record from the form and the selected value is returned to the product text box, after closing the search form. Iam having the below issue 
1. Iam not able to correctly position the search form in place of product text box. can anyone help please. below is the code

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter

    frml.Location = New Point((Me.Location.X - TextBox1.Location.X), 
             (Me.Location.Y - TextBox1.Location.Y))
    frml.Location = New Point((My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height - Me.Height),
             (My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width - Me.Width))
    frml.Show()
    frml.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: are you trying to say you want to use a DGV as if it were the drop down part of a combo?

Answer (score 0):

Set your second form start position value to Manual and remove its border:

```
Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
```

Now, you can set manually the position of frml. First, get the window height and add that value to Location. If you add the TextBox height, the form will appear under that control:

```
Dim borderHeight As Integer = Me.Height - Me.ClientSize.Height
frml.Location = New Point((Me.Location.X + TextBox1.Location.X),
     (Me.Location.Y + borderHeight + TextBox1.Location.Y + TextBox1.Height))
frml.Show()
```